# Python bytearray() index assignment

Tags: python, arrays

Bear with me here; I am a sysadmin not a developer. The following code works just fine for me. But when I break it into two files so that the class is in one file and the logic is in another I get an error that data[0] is a str and does not support assignment

Striped down working example

```
class partition:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = bytearray(b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
        return

    def boot_flag(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.data[0] = value
            return
        else:
            return self.data[0:1][::-1]


part1 = partition()
print str(part1.data).encode('hex')
value = b"\xff"
part1.boot_flag(value)
print str(part1.data).encode('hex')
```

This is the full class as it stands right now.

```
class partition:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = bytearray(b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")

    def boot_flag(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.data[0] = value
            return
        else:
            return self.data[0:1][::-1]

    def start_chs(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.data[1:4] = value
            return
        else:
            return self.data[1:4][::-1]

    def type(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.data[4:5] = value
            return
        else:
            return self.data[4:5][::-1]

    def end_chs(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.data[5:8] = value
        else:
            return self.data[5:8][::-1]

    def start_lba(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.data[8:12] = value
        else:
            return self.data[8:12][::-1]

    def sectors(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.data[12:16] = value
        else:
            return self.data[12:16][::-1]

    def load(self, data):
        self.data = data
        return
```

This is the test jig I am using to test the class.

```
import dospart
disk = open('/dev/sda', 'rb')
mbr = disk.read(512)
part1 = dospart.partition()
part1.load(mbr[446:462])
print str(part1.data).encode('hex')
part1.boot_flag(b"\xff")
print str(part1.data).encode('hex')
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    part1.boot_flag(b"\xff")
  File "/Users/digitaladdictions/PycharmProjects/dospart/dospart.py", line 9, in boot_flag
    self.data[0] = value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Note that I can read the values just fine. I only get an error when I try to write to self.data[]

[UPDATE]

Based on the accepted answer this is my new load function which works.

```
def load(self, data):
    part = bytearray(data)
    self.data = part
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what is happening. When you invoke:

```
part1.load(mbr[446:462])
```

`self.data` is being assigned a string. And that point on, `self.data` is a string and not a byte array. So when you do

```
part1.boot_flag(b"\xff")
```

it rightly complains `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

This is what I mean:

```
>>> data_one = "My name is shaktimaan"
>>> data_two = data_one[5:10]
>>> type(data_one)
<type 'str'>
```

In your first case, there is no invocation of `load` and hence `self.data` is still a byte array (after calling the constructor). So your `boot_flag` works as expected without complaining.

I think you need to fix the code in `load` to assign byte array to `self.data`

Answer (score 0):

You can't change Python strings inplace, the're immutable. You can find a lot comments about that error "'str' object does not support item assignmen". I don't know how it can work if you combine it in one file.

Comment: I guess the root of my question is why a bytearray index is being represented by a string. A bytearray object should be mutable and individual elements should be integers.

Comment: So, use bytearray not b"". `b = bytearray('\xff'); b[0] = '\xee'`